# Finding value for which systems of equations has n solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm really confused on what my professor did in lecture to get this result.

> For what $c$ does the below systems of equation 1) have one unique solution, 2) no solution, 3) infinitely many solutions

$x_1 + cx_2=1$

$2x_1+2x_2=0$

Solution: Any solution must be of the form $(t,-t)$ by the second equation, so.

$t-ct = 1$ by first equation

$t(1-c) = 1$

$t = \frac{1}{1-c}$

$c \neq 1 \Rightarrow$ unique solution

$c = 1 \Rightarrow$ no solution because division by $0$

I mostly follow this solution - except how can you be sure that $c \neq 1$ doesn't produce infinitely many solutions? What would it look like it if it did?

> For what c are the following equivalent

**I.**

$x_1 - cx_2 +0x_3= 0$

$x_1 + 0x_2 + x_3=0$

solutions $\{(-cs, -s, cs)\}$

**II.**

$2x_1 - x_2 + x_3 = 0$

$0x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$

solutions $\{(-t, t, t)\}$

for $c = 1$, they are equivalent, for $c \neq 1$ they are not equivalent.

I understand that two systems of equations are considered equivalent if they have the same solution set. But, I don't understand anything else in the above solution.

Thanks!

Comment: How much linear algebra do you know? If you know about determinants, dimension, rank etc this problem can be solved in a much more easy way

Comment: @M.Van this is the first lecture in linear algebra class. I think our professor is trying to show "the hard way" before introducing matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, you cannot have infinite solutions in the given system of equations, as for infinite solutions what you need is more variables than defining UNIQUE* equations. For any $c\neq 1$ , we will always have a single solution set (which you have already solved for).

Now let us understand this, for example if I have a single equation with two variables, say $y=2x$ , I can have as many solutions to it as I want, say I were to have an existing system of equations, if all equations are UNIQUE, i.e. not re-arrangements of each other, and I were to reduce the number of equations below the number of defined variables, then it will be similar to solving something like $y=2x$.

As for your system, if the RHS of the first equation was $0$, only then could you have infinite solutions.

Given that you have not studied matrices, I'll explain in a graphical manner.

Let us say you have the following two equations:
$2x+y=0
2y+x=0$

Now if you were to re-arrange these equation in the form of $y=mx+c$ and plot on a graph (Desmos claculator, google it), these lines would intersect at a point.

This point is where both of the equations are satisfied, i.e. your solution. As we know two straight lines can intersect only at one point. And as this is linear algebra, your lines are always straight. The co-ordinates of the point be your solution, that is why we write it as (x,y) in solution.

If you had three lines (i.e. three equations, equations > variables), it is not always possible for them to intersect at a single point, so there is the possibility of no solution.

For infinite solutions you would need the two equations to be equivalent so that both lines be the same line, something like $y+2x=-5$ and $2y+10=-4x$.

You can apply this intuition to hold valid at higher dimensions (more variables), matrices provide a better proof for higher dimensions.

*(UNIQUE means that you cannot obtain any equation in the system by re-arranging any equation or by adding,subtracting etc 2 or more equations)

Comment: I mean UNIQUE equations, i.e. you cannot obtain the equation by re-arranging any other equation or by performing operations on multiple equations, however I will add UNIQUE and a bracketed explanation for what I mean by it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For your first system, $c \neq 1$ gives a unique solution because if $c \neq 1$, like you already said an arbitrary solution will be of the form $(t,-t)$, and $t=\frac{1}{1-c}$, so the only solution will be $(\frac{1}{1-c}, \frac{1}{c-1})$. Moreover, 'no solutions because division by $0$' is not so rigorously stated. It is better to say: if $c=1$, then $x_1+x_2=1$ yields $t-t=1$, which implies $0=1$, a contradiction.

For your second system(s), you should be able to deduce the solutions by eliminating variables (I think there is a mistake in the solution sets).